# How can I center a form in Pardot?

Tags: html, css, forms, center, pardot

I am using Pardot to create a form. I am linking this form to our homepage, and would like the form to appear centered when it opens a new window.

I have been researching div's and it seems the answer is "wrap it in a div" but I am reading that pardot does not want certain things wrapped in div's. Here is the code that I am working with. I am trying to get all of this content to site nice in the middle of the page. both horizontally and somewhat vertically if possible. You can see my attempt at trying to center with the code `ontent="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1` But that does not seem to do anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://go.pardot.com" >
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="description" content="width=device-width, itintial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, %%description%%"/>
    <title>%%title%%</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">

   #pardot-form p label {
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width:250px;
    color: #003366;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 165px;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    }   



 #pardot-form.form .no-label .description {
    margin-left: 0;
    color: #003366;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 0.15em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    }
#pardot-form input.text {
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #DADADA;
    width: 200px;
    height: 2em;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
#pardot-form select {
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #DADADA;
    width: 50%;
    height: 2.5em;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
#pardot-form textarea.standard {
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #DADADA;
    width: 50%;
    height: 8em;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
#pardot-form p.submit input {
    background: #009cdb;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    }
#pardot-form.form p.submit {
    margin: 0 0 0 200px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    %%content%%
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this:

```
form.form {
display:table;
margin:0 auto !important;}
```

Just tested in Pardot and works.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Gathering all the gratitude I can and sending it across the web. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Comment: Glad it worked for you! I'm in Pardot all day so if you need additional tips, let me know.

Comment: Oh that is just music to my ears, I will keep that in mind, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
body {
  text-align:center; 
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
html {
  height:100%;
  display: table;
  width:100%;
}
```

Attached Code Pen

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xqjqWo you may need to change body and HTML to child and parent respectively but you did not have your form element in the code provided so I centered your content accordingly

You will obviously also need to replace %%content%% with your form element

Comment: will update with vertical centering as well, just re read your question.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are all genius wizards that I cannot help but admire.